# CodeIgniter - Which function to use for URL's

Tags: codeigniter

Im building my first application using CodeIgniter, i need a bit of advice.

There are 2 functions that do the same thing and i was wondering which is the best to use.

Ok, so usually when im building a site, i link to the homepage by a simple / but if building on a directory, it will take back to the root public_html directory, with codeigniter i have found both

```
site_url()
```

and

```
base_url()
```

but, they both seem to do the same thing .. Just wondering if theres any difference, which one is better to use, etc etc.

Cheers,

Comment: I don't play with CI for a long time (Kohana rocks my world), but `base_url()` should be a relative path and `site_url()` an absolute path, wich means `base_url()` will be more suitable if you think you'll need to move onto another domain latter, assuming that `base_url()` will automatically identify the domain you're working on.

Comment: Nice, thanks for that ... Just out of curiousity, why did you favour Kohana over CI?

Comment: Curious here also, haven't tried it but been using CI for a while now.

Comment: Kohana was initially a fork of CI, but it has changed drastically. It's better to try it and take your conclusions, but to give you an example, it's the only current PHP framework that implements the true meaning of HMVC and templating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using index.php

```
 site_url()
```

will include the index.php , and

```
 base_url()
```

will not include it.

If you are creating a url to pass, use

```
 site_url('images/img.png')
```

otherwise...

```
 base_url().'images/img.png'
```